# How to concatenate pairs of cells; every second cell to the first

Tags: vim, gvim

How to concatenate successive pairs of cells in a column, adding the second cell of each pair to the first.

For example:

```
santhosh
kumar
sagar
sv
sai
deva
```

And the result should be:

```
santhoshkumar
sagarsv
saidevax
```

Comment: Could you please use the formatting options to make your question more readable?

Answer (score 1):

If you have sed you can do it this way:

```
sed 'N;s/\r\?\n//' myfile.txt
```

Explanation: sed reads in the file line by line. 'N' adds the next line (i.e. line 2 if we are currently on line 1) to the buffer, then we need to remove the 'newline' that is between the 2 lines we now have in the buffer. The 's' command replaces some text on the line (as specified between the first and second slashes) with some other text (specified between the second and third slashes) - in this case we want to replace the line ending with nothing.

With Unix-type line endings this is done by removing the line feed '\n' but if it is a Windows-type document then line feed is preceded by carriage return '\r'. So \r\? is 'optional \r' where the escaped question mark indicates that the previous character may or may not exist.

Comment: The more cryptic an answer, the more explanation it needs. Please explain `N` and `\r\?`.

Comment: Happy to explain. 'N' adds the next line (i.e. line 2 if we are currently on line 1) to the buffer, then we need to remove the 'newline' that is between the 2 lines we now have in the buffer. With Unix-type line endings this is done by removing the line feed '\n' but if it is a Windows-type document then line feed is preceded by carriage return '\r'. So \r\? is 'optional \r' where the escaped question mark indicates that the previous character may or may not exist. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Given the [`gvim`](http://www.vim.org/download.php) tag, I’ll assume you're using the [`gvim`](http://www.vim.org/download.php) or [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/download.php) editor. Try the macro:

```
:map q Jxjq
```

The `J` *j*oins the two lines, leaving a space; the `x` removes that space, and the `j` moves to the next line. The `q` at the end repeats the process; it matches the `q` after the `:map` command.

That’s an old-school `vi` macro; I haven’t needed to learn the more extensive and capable `vim` macro capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

In Vi/Vim you can do something like this:

```
:g/./j!
```

Which basically means, do (`:g/`) for every non-empty line (`.`) and join it with the next without adding trailing spaces (`j!`)

Read more at the help

```
:h :g
:h :j
:h /.
```